# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException issues with public static void

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is my main...

```
public class Yamaha {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    productoYamaha p1, p2;
    p1= new productoYamaha ();
    p2= new productoYamaha ('empacador',20.00);
    p1.imprimir();
    p2.imprimir();
    System.out.println("El total a pagar es"total_a_pagar);
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

And here is the code i write

```
enter code here package yamaha;

/**
 *
 * @author Soria
 */
public class productoYamaha {
    double pProducto;
    String nProducto;

   public productoYamaha(){
       this.nProducto="";
       this.pProducto=0;
   }

   public productoYamaha (double pProducto, String nProducto){
       this.nProducto=nProducto;
       this.pProducto=pProducto;
   }
   public double gYamaha (int cantidad){
       double gcantidad;
       gcantidad= this.pProducto*cantidad;
       return gcantidad;
   }
   public void imprimir (){
       System.out.println("nombre del producto"+nProducto);
       System.out.println("precio del Producto"+pProducto);

   }
}
```

And i'm having this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: 
>       at yamaha.Yamaha.main(Yamaha.java:20)
>   C:\Users\Erick_Soria\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `p2= new productoYamaha ('empacador',20.00);` Two things: (1) the parameters seem to be backwards and (2) a `String` literal is declared using double quotes (`"`).

Comment: [I'm having now this issue...](https://imgur.com/a/1IW8T1y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your producttoYamaha constructer with arguments is

```
public productoYamaha (double pProducto, String nProducto)
```

.........

So you need to provide first argument as double and second as String and also String argument should be provided inside double quotes("empacador" ) instead single ('empacador ')

Also there is problem with print statement inside main which needs correction.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
productoYamaha p1, p2; 
p1= new productoYamaha ();
// first argument should be a double and second should be string 
p2= new productoYamaha (20.00, "empacador"); 
p1.imprimir();
p2.imprimir(); 
//concat two arguments with '+' inside print statements 
System.out.println("El total a pagar es" +total_a_pagar);
//      TODO code application logic here
 }
```